# Maven local variable "needs to be declared final" where no variable exists or where variable is already final

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am attempting to compile my program with the goals `clean package shade:shade`; however, I run into this issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/justi/Programming/YAML to Bot/YamlToBot/core/src/main/java/com/justinschaaf/yamltobot/core/setup/SetupWindow.java:[89,71] local variable module is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

From my research, the usual solution is to declare the variable as final, but **there is not a variable at line 71 and the variable at line 89 is already final**, as can be seen by `SetupWindow.java`, inserted below.

```
package com.justinschaaf.yamltobot.core.setup;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

import com.justinschaaf.yamltobot.core.common.Module;
import com.justinschaaf.yamltobot.core.common.Reference;
import com.justinschaaf.yamltobot.core.common.VersionChecker;
import com.justinschaaf.yamltobot.core.handler.ConfigHandler;

/**
 * 
 * The primary class for setting up the window for YamlToBot
 * 
 * @author Justin Schaaf
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 */
public class SetupWindow extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * The primary function for setting up the window
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public SetupWindow(Module module) {
        setTitle("YamlToBot | " + ConfigHandler.getString("name", module.getName()));
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(SetupWindow.class.getResource("/assets/icon.png")));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) header.getLayout();
        flowLayout.setVgap(0);
        flowLayout.setHgap(0);
        header.setForeground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("FEFEFE",16)));
        header.setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("283F50",16)));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_header = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_header.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc_header.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_header.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_header.gridx = 0;
        gbc_header.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(header, gbc_header);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(SetupWindow.class.getResource("/assets/logo.png")));
        header.add(label);

        final JTextArea log = new JTextArea();
        log.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

                try {

                    final File logFile = new File(module.getDir() + "logs/log-latest.log");
                    BufferedReader logText = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(logFile)));

                    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = logText.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line + "\n");
                }

                    logText.close();
                    log.setText(text.toString());

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        log.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        log.setEditable(false);
        log.setText("Move the cursor here to update the log!");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_log = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_log.gridheight = 3;
        gbc_log.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_log.gridx = 0;
        gbc_log.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(log, gbc_log);

        JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flowLayout_1 = (FlowLayout) footer.getLayout();
        flowLayout_1.setVgap(0);
        flowLayout_1.setHgap(0);
        footer.setForeground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("FEFEFE",16)));
        footer.setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("8693A4",16)));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_footer = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_footer.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbc_footer.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_footer.gridx = 0;
        gbc_footer.gridy = 5;
        contentPane.add(footer, gbc_footer);

        final JTextPane version = new JTextPane();
        version.setEditable(false);
        version.setForeground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("FEFEFE",16)));
        version.setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("8693A4",16)));
        version.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        version.setText(Reference.version);
        footer.add(version);

        final JTextPane update = new JTextPane();
        update.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (VersionChecker.isUpdated() == false) {
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(Reference.releasesURL).toURI());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        update.setEditable(false);
        update.setForeground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("FEFEFE",16)));
        update.setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt("8693A4",16)));
        update.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        update.setText(updateText());
        footer.add(update);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the jar is updated and returns text accordingly
     * @return The text stating whether or not the jar is up to date
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    private String updateText() {

        if (VersionChecker.isUpdated() == false) return "A new update is available: " + VersionChecker.getLatestVersion();
        if (Reference.prerelease == true) return "You are using a pre-release build.";
        else return "Your jar is up to date.";

    }

}
```

Line 71 is `gbc_header.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;`, and line 89 is `final File logFile = new File(module.getDir() + "logs/log-latest.log");`

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the error

> SetupWindow.java:[89,71] local variable module is accessed from within
>   inner class; needs to be declared final

It tells that the variable named `module` is not final. You can't use a non-final local variable that is declared outside the anonymous inner class, inside that inner class.

You are using `module` in line 89 as `module.getDir()`.

Also, 89 is the line number, 71 is the column or character number in that line.

To fix it, change `public SetupWindow(Module module)` to `public SetupWindow(final Module module)`.